# MySQL csv import incremental slowdown (alternatives?)

Tags: mysql, csv, import, slowdown

I have the following table:

```
CREATE  TABLE `Product_Category_Rank` (
  `CategoryId` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `ProductId` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL ,
  `RankedOn` DATE NOT NULL ,
  `PopularityRank` SMALLINT(5) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CategoryId`, `ProductId`, `RankedOn`) ,
  INDEX `fk_Product_Category_Rank_Product` (`ProductId` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_Product_Category_Rank_Category` (`CategoryId` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Product_Category_Rank_Category`
    FOREIGN KEY (`CategoryId` )
    REFERENCES `Category` (`CategoryId` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Product_Category_Rank_Product`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ProductId` )
    REFERENCES `Product` (`ProductId` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci
```

I have a csv file (which I am importing daily) that contains just under 30,000 records.

I have tried:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'temp/product_category_rank.csv'
INTO TABLE `Product_Category_Rank`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

As well I have tried loading the file into a temporary table and doing:

```
INSERT
  INTO `Product_Category_Rank` ( ... )
SELECT ...
  FROM `tmp_product_category_rank`
```

Both methods work equally (same results), however the second I am sure has a slightly higher resource cost. The problem I am running into is that every day the import time on the load / insert-select functionality is increasing by about 3 seconds / day.  So day 30 I am looking at 90 seconds to do a straight import into the table.

Facts: the import will *never* have duplicate primary keys (unless of course I try to import the same data twice, which is not an issue)

So is there a way to speed up this process (maybe turning off key checking before the import? (how?))

edit: Also to note that the foreign key checks are not required either as the Category and Product tables have already been updated and the foreign key constraints are not an issue with the import.

Comment: I feel like I've read somewhere that dropping the indexes, doing the import, and re-adding the indexes is faster than importing with the indexes on.  I would do some test cases before trying it on the real data, though.

Comment: @Sam Dufel What I am wondering is if there is maybe a way to disable key and foreign key checks during the import

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks

Comment: @Sam Dufel Yes (am googling away here too, and I have tried wrapping the LOAD in between SET foreign_key_checks = 0; and SET foreign_key_checks = 1; does not appear to be having any effect (speed wise)

Comment: @Sam Dufel Scratch that, maybe it is helping, going to do some more benchmarking here and will update shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: (Apparently had nothing to do with the query)

MySQL server variables:

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 8MB (changed to 2GB)
innodb_log_file_size = 5MB (changed to 256MB)
innodb_log_buffer_size = 1MB (changed to 4MB)
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1 (changed to 2)

These new settings are based on an article found at :
http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/11/01/innodb-performance-optimization-basics/

Now as I run the import, there is no degradation to the speed of the imports on a day to day basis.  I have imported 30 days and each import is the same speed as the last.  So it was actually a server optimization issue.